# Which toolkit should I convert my existing MFC project to?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have a quite big MFC project all with unmanaged C++ code and MFC GUI. From

[What's new in Visual Studio 2013 for native development](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632831/Whats-new-in-Visual-Studio-2013-for-native-develop),

[ATL and MFC changes and fixes in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/08/20/atl-and-mfc-changes-and-fixes-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

I know MFC was never ever dying as fast as now.So I have to start to consider where my project should go, in other words, what I should convert my project to, I have to do this sooner or later.

If I start a new project form scratch, I know the alternative would probably be QT, but the question is also, if I want to do so, how could we convert the code to QT?

Comment: Even if MFC isn't the latest and greatest, it isn't going away. Don't rewrite your app unless you have other compelling reasons to do so. This old blog post is still relevant: [Things You Should Never Do, Part I](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

Comment: MFC is probably still your best bet. It can integrate with .NET and WPF, allowing you to gradually move towards managed code. Switching to Qt has 2 immediate effects: Your customers will complain about a sluggish GUI. And broken keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Questions to ask yourself or your boss or manager:

Is it worth the time and money to convert your application? Will you be paid to do that ? will it bring extra revenues to you and/or your company ? 
Can you spare weeks of re-factoring for a new framework without working on other issues and improvements that will bring in more money to you ?

Do you have any deal-breaker or critical issues with the current MFC and C++ implementation that you have to fix or workaround ? Most issues can be worked around

Are there features in other toolkit that you cannot live without ? 
Do you feel like you are always re-inventing the wheel for basic features that are already supported by other toolkits?